# Node-Red: JSON integration into Insert-Statement

Tags: json, postgresql, node-red, stringify

In Node-Red is there a way to integrate a JSON-Msg, into an INSERT-Statement as a string without the usage of stringify? Because after 2000 Characters, the Message is cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Messages shown in the debug sidebar are truncated for performance reasons, the actual message is not truncated.

You can see the whole message by sending it to the console (with the tick box in the debug node).

You can also edit/set the `debugMaxLength` in settings.js to change the truncation point.